# Can't play mp3 file in C#

Tags: c#, mp3

I'm using this solution to try to play an mp3 file in C# which I have inside a class library using this code: http://www.geekpedia.com/code111_Play-MP3-Files-Using-Csharp.html

I'm creating an instance, and calling the play method after opening a file and it doesn't play the mp3 file. Is this method deprecated nowadays as it dates back to 2008 or should this be working still?

Also worth pointing out, this is for a console application on Windows.

Comment: Which values return mciSendString?

Comment: Have you tried the following library? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @codroipo `13229323905401098` when opening the file and 
`1970324836974855` when attempting to play

Comment: @Alex as i'm using console, I dont think I can?

Comment: Yes, you can use @Alex solution in a console application

Comment: @user3791372 [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd757161(v=vs.85).aspx) says that the returned type is `MCIERROR`, that is defined as `DWORD`, so an `int`. Can you try to define the PInvoke as `static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback);` then reexecute the code and tell me again the error codes?

Comment: @codroipo 266 when opening (            MCIERR_CANNOT_LOAD_DRIVER = 266,), and 263 on playing

Comment: Error codes are defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228215(v=vs.60).aspx), so your problem is MCIERR_CANNOT_LOAD_DRIVER.

Comment: it would appear that this code has to be run in a sta thread

Comment: @user3791372 You should consider writing that as an answer because there are some questions about this and none of them are solved

Answer (score 0):

The code that is linked to in the question has to be run from an STA thread, otherwise it will not work.